# generate point in random direction from center

Tags: java

I am trying to randmly create set of points with random position of an initial point.
Unfortunatly almost all of my generated points are located in upper left corner. Is there a mistake in my calculations?

```
private void makePath() {

    int r = 25;
    Random rand = new Random();
    double angle = Math.toRadians(rand.nextInt(361));
    int nx = (int) (x + r * Math.cos(angle));
    int ny = (int) (y - r * Math.sin(angle));
    path.add(new Point2D(nx, ny));
```

}

Comment: Do you know what a "radian" is?

Comment: Thanks, I understood.I wrongly assumed it is in degrees.

Comment: @SteveC I've changed degrees to radians; points are still gererated in upper left corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the values, try using:

```
int nx = (int) (x + r * Math.cos(angle));
int ny = (int) (y + r * Math.sin(angle));
```

Using `y + r * ...` instead. This is coming from a method I wrote to do the exact same thing:

```
/**
 * Generates a new point within a circular radius from
 * the given <tt>x</tt> and <tt>y</tt> coordinates. This
 * is done by generating a random offset along the
 * horizontal axis, then applying a rotation.
 *
 * @param seed The seed to generate the point from.
 * @param x    The x coordinate of the center of the
 *             circle.
 * @param y    The y coordinate of the center of the
 *             circle.
 * @return The newly generated point, within the
 * specified radius of the point <tt>(x, y)
 * </tt>.
 * @see ClusterGenerator#RADIUS
 */

private static Point makePoint(final Random seed, final int x, final int y) {
    final int offset = seed.nextInt(RADIUS);
    final double rotation = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
    final int x1 = (int) (Math.sin(rotation) * offset);
    final int y1 = (int) (Math.cos(rotation) * offset);
    return new Point(x + x1, y + y1);
}
```

Comment: It looks correct but my points are still drown in upper left corner

Comment: @Yarh are you sure you are using `x` and `y` as the center and not the top-left corner for the circle?